# VTK's example not running on Android

Tags: android, vtk

I compiled vtk-9.1 library, and I got 58 .a static lib.
then imported lib into AndroidStudio , config CMake and make it working in my project.also,I copyed code from official android example,so far so good!
but when the official Android example(VolumeRender) running, it's nothing on the screen but only black,I'm so confused.

1. I tested my jni code that is working!
2. I compiled vtk-8.2 library,but it was crashed when i runing it on my phone,I found it was because
   `vtkRenderWindow *renWin = vtkRenderWindow::New();`
   return NULL
3. I compiled vtk-master,it was same problem as vtk-9.1

anyone can help?

**the example's url**: https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/tree/master/Examples/Android/VolumeRender

by the way,My Android Project's CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

project(vtkapplication)
add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

# Specifies a path to native header files.
include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/)

find_library( # Defines the name of the path variable that stores the
        # location of the NDK library.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # CMake needs to locate.
        log)
# add openGL es
find_path(GLES2_INCLUDE_DIR GLES2/gl2.h
        HINTS ${ANDROID_NDK})              
find_library(GLES2_LIBRARY libGLESv2.so
        HINTS ${GLES2_INCLUDE_DIR}/../lib) 
include_directories(
        ${GLES2_INCLUDE_DIR}               
)
set(OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR ${GLES2_INCLUDE_DIR})


set(VTK_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/cmake/vtk-9.1)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)

include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

# Links your native library against one or more other native libraries.
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        android
        ${log-lib}
        EGL
        GLESv2
        GLESv3
        ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
```

Comment: VTK master should build with android

Comment: thanks for your answer! no, it was same problem as vtk-9.1 , noting but black screen

Comment: 9.1 is not master

Comment: I mean I have compiled vtk-master already,and import vtk-master into Android Project,but also it display black screen,don't rendering anything!sorry for my pool english.